# How to disable selection of cells in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-ng2

I have a simple ag-grid in an Angular project and want to disable selection of cells in one of its columns.  Simply removing the default blue outline during selection would also be fine.  I just want no visual change to the cell when the user clicks inside it.  How can I do this?

I see that `ColDef` has a property `suppressNavigable` that sort of helps, since it disallows using the tab key to select the cells, but it still allows selection by clicking. Also, the grid itself seems to offer `suppressCellSelection` but it doesn't seem granular enough and doesn't seem to affect anything anyway.

So, how can I remove this blue border cell selection?

Here's the code I have for these column definitions:

```js
this.columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'One', field: 'one' },
  { headerName: 'Two', field: 'two' },
  { 
    // I want to disable selection of cells in this column
    headerName: 'I want no cell selection!', 
    field: 'three',   
    suppressNavigable: true,
    editable: false,
  }
];
```

Here's a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/aggrid-want-to-disable-cell-selection) I was using to test with.

Here's a screenshot of the blue border I don't want to see in this column:

[image: I don't want to see the blue border]

Comment: Pls help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018177/ag-grid-community-infinite-row-model-for-server-side-pagination-community-free/65040658#65040658

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> Note that if we set `gridOption.suppressCellSelection = true` we can disable cell selection for all columns' cells.
>
> Here the question is regarding not showing a specific column's cell's highlighted border when it is selected.

You can achieve this by bit of CSS and `cellClass` property of `ColDef`.

You'll need to add below CSS.

```
.ag-cell-focus,.ag-cell-no-focus{
  border:none !important;
}
/* This CSS is to not apply the border for the column having 'no-border' class */
.no-border.ag-cell:focus{
  border:none !important;
  outline: none;
}
```

And use the same class as `cellClass` in `ColDef`

```
suppressNavigable: true,
cellClass: 'no-border'
```

Live example: [aggrid-want-to-disable-cell-selection](https://stackblitz.com/edit/aggrid-want-to-disable-cell-selection-wnkzee?file=src/app/app.component.ts)
This won't show border for the cell you even focus using mouse click.

---

#### Update

As per [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) [Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/keyboard-navigation/#suppress-cell-focus) and comment mentioned by X.Aurther, the option has been renamed to `suppressCellFocus`.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! It's quick to help when the reproduced issue is shared.

Comment: Why not `suppressCellSelection` in gridOptions?

Comment: PO just want to disable it for a single column. Not for all column. The issue is styling for the selected cell which is suppressed from navigation

Comment: For me it worked only with `::ng-deep` before `.no-border.ag-cell:focus`. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This prevents the selection in a visible way, but the grid api will still consider the cell selected.

Comment: @xandermonkey - thats right, but here PO's intention is just regarding the UI aspect of this.

Comment: How would you prevent cell selection for all columns? Do I have to repeat `cellClass` for every single header?

Comment: Nvm, just add `::ng-deep .ag-cell:focus{
  border: none !important;
  outline: none;
}` to your css

Comment: suppressClickEdit

Comment: I would set `border: 1px solid transparent !important;` otherwise the border is added and removed and size of rows change thus it is "jumpy" when you select

Comment: note that the option has been renamed into `suppressCellFocus`.

Answer (score 35):

I'd suggest to use the `suppressCellSelection` option in gridOptions. A CSS quick fix is not something that I'd suggest to go for.

```
this.gridOptions = {
  // Your grid options here....
  suppressCellSelection: true
};
```

As suggested by [@aderchox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9868445/aderchox), from v27.0 onwards, the option has been renamed to `suppressCellFocus`.

Comment: That option is already set in my gridoptions. It doesn't help.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer make sure enableRangeSelection is false

Comment: Worked from me thanks !!

Comment: Amazing, solved 10 problems together for me :D. Only for future visitors: Notice that in newer versions of AG Grid it's been replaced by `suppressCellFocus` (since v27.0).

Answer (score 6):

You can try this css hack. no custom flags needed.

```
.ag-cell-focus, .ag-cell {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/aggrid-want-to-disable-cell-selection-answer?file=src%2Fstyles.css

[image]

Comment: This only removes the highlight. The keyboard navigation behavior is retained, so you'll get strange behavior with the left and right arrow keys if your table scrolls horizontally.

Comment: This post answers the OP's question in that OP said "Simply removing the default blue outline during selection would also be fine".  And it does exactly that.   Amazing that this got downvoted.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`cellStyle`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/#cell-style) to remove the selection dynamically. Here is an example:

```js
{
  headerName: "Is Selectable",
  cellStyle: (params) => {
    if (!params.value) {
      return { border: "none" };
    }
    return null;
  },
  ...
},
{
  headerName: "UnSelectable",
  cellStyle: { border: "none" },
  ...
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 50862009/how-to-disable-selection-of-cells-in-ag-grid/50863144#50863144]

Comment: Working solution for a specific cell. Thank you: cellStyle: { border: "none" }

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it's work for me

```
::ng-deep .ag-cell-focus,.ag-cell-no-focus{
border:none !important;
}
::ng-deep .no-border.ag-cell:focus{
border:none !important;
outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, If you want to apply it over all the cells.
It worked for me.

```
.ag-cell-focus,.ag-cell-no-focus{
  border: 1px solid transparent !important;
}

::ng-deep .ag-cell:focus{
  border: 1px solid transparent !important;
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AG Grid supports customizing CSS variable for most themes. Try defining the selection border color on the grid container or any parent.

```css
--ag-range-selection-border-color: transparent;
```

[AG Grid: Setting colour parameters using CSS variables](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/themes-customising/#setting-colour-parameters-using-css-variables)

Answer (score 0):

this workd guys
add this line inside same props className="ag-theme-alpine"
.ag-cell-focus,
.ag-cell-no-focus {
border: none !important;
}
/* This CSS is to not apply the border for the column having 'no-border' class */
.no-border.ag-cell:focus {
border: none !important;
outline: none;
}