# Temporarily disable row selection in AG Grid (Angular)

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

My grid looks as follows (community edition), allowing the user to select rows (checkbox defined on column definition)

```html
    <ag-grid-angular 
        *ngIf='!isLoading && model.length > 0'
        style="height: 70vh;" class="ag-theme-balham"
        [rowData]="model" 
        [animateRows]="true" 
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions" 
        [rowSelection]='rowSelection'
        [enableCellTextSelection]="true" 
        [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate"
        (cellDoubleClicked)="onCellDoubleClicked($event)"
        (selectionChanged)="onRecordSelected($event)" 
        (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

One half of the page show the grid, the other part an edit for for the selected record.

While the form get saved, I'd like to disable selection in the grid.
Is this possible?  (maybe i'm being stupid, but could not figure out a way)

Comment: check the approved answer, hope this is what you are asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862009/how-to-disable-selection-of-cells-in-ag-grid .

Answer (score 4):

AG Grid [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/) indicates that for a row click selection (like using a checkbox selection), you can set `suppressRowClickSelection` to `true` to disable selection.

You can hold a boolean value in a component property - eg. `suppressRowClick` and set `suppressRowClickSelection` in the template equal to `suppressRowClick`.

You can update `suppressRowClick` in the component via a method that suits your project:

1. @Input() from a parent component, or
2. Create a service to manage `suppressRowClick` and update from sibling component, or
3. Use a state management framework like NgRX or Akita (overkill unless already using)

Comment: I realize now that `suppressRowClickSelection` can be used binding it to a property I already have (isBusy).  However this does not prevent the user from changing the selection using the checkboxes.

Comment: Also it is possible to click custom cellRendererFramework I got for one column (pretty much render a link).  So seems nothing available to say "disable this entire grid".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to disable the entire grid a way to disable the entire grid is by using the overlays, which you are using already so perhaps I am misunderstanding the question. if you don't want to see the loading box, in the html this line does that:

```
   <ag-grid-angular
        #agGrid
        [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate"
...
 
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

In the component set the

```
 overlayLoadingTemplate =
    '<span></span>';
```

Then in the component use this function to set the overlay when you want it to be disabled:

```
this.gridApi.showLoadingOverlay();
```

This worked for me hope it can help others.